# Firebase Protobuf pod causes errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, firebase, cocoapods

Firebase install Protobuf pod in my project . When I compile I have these errors:

[image]

I don't know what can I do. I use xcode 9 and a swift 4 / objective-C hybrid project

Comment: Any warnings on pod update? Can you share Podfile?

Comment: Instead of adding screenshots of your code, please add the actual code to the question. To capture the error message, right click on the red indicator and "Reveal in Issue Navigator".